# Red Question Mark - Secret room on map Inaccessible - TBOI Repentance

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

There is no way I can find to get to this room I circled and have never seen it before. I am on the corpse floor 1.

[image: What is this?]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These red secret rooms are called [Ultra Secret Rooms](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.fandom.com/wiki/Secret_Room#Ultra_Secret_Rooms). They can only be accessed by creating a new room adjacent to it or by teleporting to it using the reversed card "XVIII - The Moon?". You can create new rooms by using the item Red Key, the trinket Crystal Key, or the consumables Cracked Key or Soul of Cain.